# sed adding text from matching pattern and add if pattern doesn't exist

Tags: sed

I'm hoping there's someone that could help with this. I'm most certain the question have been asked however, i'm having some difficulty understanding some of the answers.

I have the following text in file.txt

```
value1=192.168.1.2

value2=10.1.1.15
```

I'd like to replace those ip address and add value3=10.224.100.5 if value3 doesn't exist, using sed.

What i have so far or at least tried.

```
sed \ 
 -e '/^#\?\(\s*value1\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\newvalue/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
 -e '$avalue1=newvalue' \
 -e '/^#\?\(\s*value2\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\newvalue/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
 -e '$avalue2=newvalue' \
 -e '/^#\?\(\s*value3\s*=\s*\).*/{s//\newvalue/;:a;n;ba;q}' \
 -e '$avalue3=newvalue' file.txt
```

This works fine if value(1,2,3) doesn't exist however, if value1 exists in file.txt, it stops at 1.

I'm assuming its because of the ;q

Any advice please? i'm really having a hard time getting this.

Comment: awk can be easier, if it is also acceptable.

Comment: i'm open to any ideas at this stage

Comment: ok, my answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with awk:

```
awk -v v1="new1" -v v2="new2" 
   'BEGIN{FS=OFS="=";addV3=1}
   $1=="value1"{$2=v1}
   $1=="value2"{$2=v2}
   $1=="value3"{addV3=0}7;
   END{if(addV3)print "value3=newV3"}' file
```

### test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
value1=192.168.1.2
value2=10.1.1.15 

kent$  awk -v v1="new1" -v v2="new2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="=";addV3=1}$1=="value1"{$2=v1}$1=="value2"{$2=v2}$1=="value3"{addV3=0}7;END{if(addV3)print "value3=newV3"}' f   
value1=new1
value2=new2
value3=newV3
```

Comment: For someone new to `awk` - what is the `7` in this expression: `$1=="value3"{addV3=0}7;` doing? It looked like a typo but it's integral to having this run exactly as requested.